# Can I create one Client and reuse it for all my functional tests?

Tags: php, symfony, testing, functional-testing

**tl;dr: Will this potentially keep my tests from working properly?**

I'm trying to write functional tests for my Symfony project, and working from examples in [The Symfony Book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#your-first-functional-test). So far, each method of the test class starts out with the same line of code:

```
namespace Tests\AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class SomeControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testSomethingOnRouteX()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        // set up and assert
    }

    public function testSomethingElseOnRouteX()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        // different set up and assert
    }
}
```

I would like to remove this redundant code, but I am not sure if I should do this.

I added a constructor where I created the client.

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->client = static::createClient();
}
```

then in the various test methods I can just use `$this->client` without needing to create it repeatedly. This seems to work so far (I don't have many tests yet.) But I'm new enough to this framework, and to this type of testing in general that I'm not sure if it will cause problems down the road.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way to do it is to either use the `setUp()` method, or the `@before` hook. Both are called before each test method, so you're safe as the state won't be shared between test cases. Cleanup is also done for you automatically after each test case is run (implemented in the `WebTestCase` class).

```php
namespace Tests\AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client;

class SomeControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var Client
     */
    private $client;

    protected setUp()
    {
        $this->client = self::createClient();
    }

    public function testSomethingOnRouteX()
    {
        // set up and assert
        $this->client->request('GET', '/something');
    }

    public function testSomethingElseOnRouteX()
    {
        // different set up and assert
        $this->client->request('GET', '/something-else');
    }
}
```

Alternatively to `setUp()` you can use the `@before` hook:

```
namespace Tests\AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client;

class SomeControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var Client
     */
    private $client;

    /**
     * @before
     */
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->client = self::createClient();
    }

    // ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try it, you should probably use the setUp-method instead. Reusing a client might introduce side effects, which is something you try to avoid. If your tests start to randomly fail, you probably want to try to go back to creating a new client per test. I wouldn't recommend it, but more from a gut feeling than actual bad experience. It should work fine most of the time, but when you suddenly reuse a client with for example a differently set header and it doesn't work you will have a headache.

I don't think there will be a huge performance gain as ui-tests are slow anyway, so trying to have as few test cases is probably a better way to go (look for test pyramid, if you don't know what I mean) if that's your aim.

Comment: +1.  I used to try making a single client in `setUpBeforeClass()` and it often had trouble with memory issues on any request past the first. Each test is a separate instance and it is probably best to treat them as such.

Answer (score 0):

It may work or may not work, depending on what you're testing.

A new client is like a fresh browser installation. No cookies are set, no history, no `actual` page, and so on.

If you're testing auth for example, it would be really bad if `testCanNotAccessInternalResourceIfNotLoggedIn` would use the client which is still logged in because `testLogInWithCorrectCredentialsWorks` ran before it and therefore fails. Sure, you can make sure you logout the user before accessing the resource but just creating a clean new browser instance is the easiest and least error-prone way to do it.